# How to decompose this list comprehension or in other word, how to merge subsets in a list?

Tags: python

I follow some tips but still cannot decompose this list comprehension, what this mean in the middle list? It is mainly for merging some subsets in a list, for example

```
l1 = ['员工:张三', '实习员工:张三', '职员:李四']
```

because `'员工:张三'` is the subset of `'实习员工:张三'`, the reuslt will remove `'员工:张三'`

```
l1_res = [word for word in l1 if not any(word in other != word for other in l1)]
```

I know the outer may like, but what about inner?

```
l1_res = []
for word in l1:
    if not any(word in other!=word for other in l1): #how to decompose this line?
         l1_res.append(word)
```

Or anyother way to implement this function?

Comment: @Patrick `word in other != word` means `word in other and other != word`…

Comment: I try to avoid python chained comparisons in list cmps - i get confused.

Comment: @deceze could you please have a look, I add more detail into my question and thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be decomposed to:

```
l1_res = []
for word in l1:
    for other in l1:
        if word in other != word:
            break
    else:
         l1_res.append(word)
```

This uses *two* of Python's easily misleading constructs:

- chained comparison for `word in other != word`, meaning `word in other and other != word`
- [`for..else`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement), where the `else` will be executed only if the loop wasn't `broken`, err, `break` wasn't invoked

Alternatively you can also do:

```
l1_res = []
for word in l1:
    found = False
    for other in l1:
        if word in other != word:
            found = True
            break
    if not found:
         l1_res.append(word)
```

Comment: In a now removed comment it was suggested the complete thing should eleminate longer versions of "ABCDE:123" in favor of "CDE:123"  because "CDE:123" is contained in "ABCDE:!23" - which his thing does not accomplish - but commment vanished so may not be that important anymore

Answer (score 0):

Here you have equivalent code based on standard loops:

```
l1_res = []
for word in l1:
  tmp = []
  for other in l1:
    tmp.append(word in other != word)
  if not any(tmp):
    l1_res.append(word)
print(l1_res)
```

Comment: It's not exactly equivalent, since it doesn't short-circuit the `for other in l1` iteration if something was found.

Comment: @deceze: Ohh yes you're right, sorry I forgot that `any` will stop immediately after True is found.

Answer (score -2):

```
l1 = ['a', 'ab','c','abc']
l1_res = []
for word in l1:
    tmp = []
    for other in l1:
        tmp.append( word in other and other != word)  # word in other != word
    if not any(tmp):
        l1_res.append(word)
print(l1_res)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.